# jQuery DataTable - how to display the value as a percentage of column total?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using the jQuery [DataTables plugin](https://datatables.net/). My basic table is like

```
+-------+--------+
| Name  | Stones |
+-------+--------+
| Wilma |     50 |
| Betty |     10 |
+-------+--------+
```

And I was hoping to use a column render function to render the 'stones' number based on the whole column of data. (e.g. to include a percentage so Betty's might show like `10 (20%)`

The `columns.render` option looked useful in that it allows you to provide the HTML that will be used to render a particular cell. However I can't see a way to access the column data for the cell being rendered (which is required to generate aggregate stats, or a percentage etc.)

We get the column (and row) index, but there's no reference I can find to the whole table data set, as would be needed to calculate the percentage-of-column (or similar).

Even doing a hideously inefficient "get api → get data in the columns of the one being rendered → do calcs" loop does not work because the column data is only populated as far as the row in question.

At the mo the only way I can see to do it is to parse the whole table myself for each column, calculate the aggregate data there and pass it in as a closure to the column.render function.

I'm new to using DataTable but I've read loads on the API reference and can't find out how to do this; yet it seems like a pretty normal thing to want to do, so perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: If you could source your DataTable using AJAX or JavaScript object, at least, you wouldn't have that problem.

Comment: Thanks. That's kinda what I meant when I said that I could parses the table for data myself: if I did that I would have access to the data and/or I could provide that data as an object to DataTables. I would prefer to do something with Vuejs or d3 anyway, but I'm trying to stay within the libraries common to the project, and also to enhance an existing table.

Comment: I would say, feeding your table with ajax/js data source instead of HTML would be the ultimate improvement from both performance and code clearance standpoints.